# Swift get Data from Web

Tags: ios, web, swift

I got a small problem that i really dont understand, if i try get the content from stackoverflow it works but if i replace it with for example google it does not work.

The app simply crashes on that task.resume()

```
var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.stackoverflow.com") // <-google.com does not work

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url){(data, response, error) in

            println(data)
            println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use other encoding like NSASCIIStringEncoding (google.com page contains some pure js functions, so I assume it will crash with NSUTF8StringEncoding) ? :D